# Python when i click button twice qgridlayoutwidget gets weird

Tags: python, pyqt5, grid-layout

## **-SOLVED-**

Hello I recently made a program which gets imdb api (non-official one) and generate bbcode

You can see my code here: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/yiXfjrFu)

```
    def _search(self):
    if self.inputBox.text() != '':
        srchRes = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=2ee068f3&s='+self.inputBox.text().replace(" ", "%20")))
        if srchRes['Response'] == 'True':
            self.info.hide()
            self.title1.show()
            self.title1.setText(srchRes['Search'][0]['Title'] + ' (' + srchRes['Search'][0]['Type'].capitalize() + ' ' + srchRes['Search'][0]['Year'] + ')')
            self.sel1.show()
            if int(srchRes['totalResults']) > 1:
                self.title2.show()
                self.title2.setText(srchRes['Search'][1]['Title'] + ' (' + srchRes['Search'][1]['Type'].capitalize() + ' ' + srchRes['Search'][1]['Year'] + ')')
                self.sel2.show()
            else:
                self.title2.hide()
                self.sel2.hide()
                self.title3.hide()
                self.sel3.hide()
                self.title4.hide()
                self.sel4.hide()
                self.title5.hide()
                self.sel5.hide()
                self.title6.hide()
                self.sel6.hide()
                self.title7.hide()
                self.sel7.hide()
                self.title8.hide()
                self.sel8.hide()
                self.title9.hide()
                self.sel9.hide()
                self.title10.hide()
                self.sel10.hide()
                self.gridLayout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 560, 50))
                Dialog.resize(600, 150)
                return
            if int(srchRes['totalResults']) > 2:
                self.title3.show()
                self.title3.setText(srchRes['Search'][2]['Title'] + ' (' + srchRes['Search'][2]['Type'].capitalize() + ' ' + srchRes['Search'][2]['Year'] + ')')
                self.sel3.show()
            else:
                self.title3.hide()
                self.sel3.hide()
                self.title4.hide()
                self.sel4.hide()
                self.title5.hide()
                self.sel5.hide()
                self.title6.hide()
                self.sel6.hide()
                self.title7.hide()
                self.sel7.hide()
                self.title8.hide()
                self.sel8.hide()
                self.title9.hide()
                self.sel9.hide()
                self.title10.hide()
                self.sel10.hide()
                self.gridLayout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 560, 100))
                Dialog.resize(600, 200)
                return
            if int(srchRes['totalResults']) > 3:
                self.title4.show()
                self.title4.setText(srchRes['Search'][3]['Title'] + ' (' + srchRes['Search'][3]['Type'].capitalize() + ' ' + srchRes['Search'][3]['Year'] + ')')
                self.sel4.show()
            else:
                self.title4.hide()
                self.sel4.hide()
                self.title5.hide()
                self.sel5.hide()
                self.title6.hide()
                self.sel6.hide()
                self.title7.hide()
                self.sel7.hide()
                self.title8.hide()
                self.sel8.hide()
                self.title9.hide()
                self.sel9.hide()
                self.title10.hide()
                self.sel10.hide()
                self.gridLayout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 560, 150))
                Dialog.resize(600, 250)
                return
            if int(srchRes['totalResults']) > 4:
                self.title5.show()
                self.title5.setText(srchRes['Search'][4]['Title'] + ' (' + srchRes['Search'][4]['Type'].capitalize() + ' ' + srchRes['Search'][4]['Year'] + ')')
                self.sel5.show()
            else:
                self.title5.hide()
                self.sel5.hide()
                self.title6.hide()
                self.sel6.hide()
                self.title7.hide()
                self.sel7.hide()
                self.title8.hide()
                self.sel8.hide()
                self.title9.hide()
                self.sel9.hide()
                self.title10.hide()
                self.sel10.hide()
                self.gridLayout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 560, 200))
                Dialog.resize(600, 300)
                return
            if int(srchRes['totalResults']) > 5:
                self.title6.show()
                self.title6.setText(srchRes['Search'][5]['Title'] + ' (' + srchRes['Search'][5]['Type'].capitalize() + ' ' + srchRes['Search'][5]['Year'] + ')')
                self.sel6.show()
            else:
                self.title6.hide()
                self.sel6.hide()
                self.title7.hide()
                self.sel7.hide()
                self.title8.hide()
                self.sel8.hide()
                self.title9.hide()
                self.sel9.hide()
                self.title10.hide()
                self.sel10.hide()
                self.gridLayout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 560, 250))
                Dialog.resize(600, 350)
                return
            if int(srchRes['totalResults']) > 6:
                self.title7.show()
                self.title7.setText(srchRes['Search'][6]['Title'] + ' (' + srchRes['Search'][6]['Type'].capitalize() + ' ' + srchRes['Search'][6]['Year'] + ')')
                self.sel7.show()
            else:
                self.title7.hide()
                self.sel7.hide()
                self.title8.hide()
                self.sel8.hide()
                self.title9.hide()
                self.sel9.hide()
                self.title10.hide()
                self.sel10.hide()
                self.gridLayout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 560, 300))
                Dialog.resize(600, 400)
                return
            if int(srchRes['totalResults']) > 7:
                self.title8.show()
                self.title8.setText(srchRes['Search'][7]['Title'] + ' (' + srchRes['Search'][7]['Type'].capitalize() + ' ' + srchRes['Search'][7]['Year'] + ')')
                self.sel8.show()
            else:
                self.title8.hide()
                self.sel8.hide()
                self.title9.hide()
                self.sel9.hide()
                self.title10.hide()
                self.sel10.hide()
                self.gridLayout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 560, 350))
                Dialog.resize(600, 450)
                return
            if int(srchRes['totalResults']) > 8:
                self.title9.show()
                self.title9.setText(srchRes['Search'][8]['Title'] + ' (' + srchRes['Search'][8]['Type'].capitalize() + ' ' + srchRes['Search'][8]['Year'] + ')')
                self.sel9.show()
            else:
                self.title9.hide()
                self.sel9.hide()
                self.title10.hide()
                self.sel10.hide()
                self.gridLayout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 560, 400))
                Dialog.resize(600, 500)
                return
            if int(srchRes['totalResults']) > 9:
                self.title10.show()
                self.title10.setText(srchRes['Search'][9]['Title'] + ' (' + srchRes['Search'][9]['Type'].capitalize() + ' ' + srchRes['Search'][9]['Year'] + ')')
                self.sel10.show()
                self.gridLayout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 560, 500))
                Dialog.resize(600, 600)
            else:
                self.title10.hide()
                self.sel10.hide()
                self.gridLayout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 560, 450))
                Dialog.resize(600, 550)
                return
        else:
            self.title1.hide()
            self.sel1.hide()
            self.title2.hide()
            self.sel2.hide()
            self.title3.hide()
            self.sel3.hide()
            self.title4.hide()
            self.sel4.hide()
            self.title5.hide()
            self.sel5.hide()
            self.title6.hide()
            self.sel6.hide()
            self.title7.hide()
            self.sel7.hide()
            self.title8.hide()
            self.sel8.hide()
            self.title9.hide()
            self.sel9.hide()
            self.title10.hide()
            self.sel10.hide()
            Dialog.resize(600, 100)
    else:
            self.title1.hide()
            self.sel1.hide()
            self.title2.hide()
            self.sel2.hide()
            self.title3.hide()
            self.sel3.hide()
            self.title4.hide()
            self.sel4.hide()
            self.title5.hide()
            self.sel5.hide()
            self.title6.hide()
            self.sel6.hide()
            self.title7.hide()
            self.sel7.hide()
            self.title8.hide()
            self.sel8.hide()
            self.title9.hide()
            self.sel9.hide()
            self.title10.hide()
            self.sel10.hide()
            Dialog.resize(600, 100)
```

The code above is my search function...

Every time I put a keyword and click Search Button, it seems to work well, but clicking the button twice causes an grid layout crash. I don't really find the problem.

Can anyone look at my code and find out the problem? It would be more thankful if you optimize my code.. not necessarily

Comment: Tell us what have you tried so far to analyze the problem.

Comment: I tried to modify self.gridLayout.setGeometry() part in various ways, but nothing really worked...

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Have you debugged it? What tools have you used for debugging? How exactly have you debugged it?

Comment: actually i solved it right now

Comment: the problem was the QtCore.Qrect() i forgot that this thing is a relative positioning

Comment: Great. Put you answer via the answer button. It can help others who face similar problem. Also change your question from "gets weird" to something more understandable.

Comment: I see you are working with GUI so if you are new I just wanted to ask if you have tried PySimpleGUI ? It has everything just very simple to code the coolest layouts and the sky is the limit. Hope I dont break any rules by recommending it.

Comment: i actually designed it using Qt Designer, and modified with notepad++... i like classic ways

Comment: cool you solved it already, the most important is what YOU like, I just like to pass along my discoveries :) I have actually seen top notch programmers using notepad++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Solution**

When using QtCore.QRect(), you should be careful not  to set position twice.

In my case, I defined the Grid position on line 66, and re-defined it in the function _search, which caused the problem. So, when you are re-defining, you should use it like

```
QtCore.QRect(0, 0, Horizontal_size, Vertical_size)
```

hope it helped others